# How to minus the date from the current date in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, xmi

I am new to SAP and XMI.  I have a report that when the page loads it automatically gets the data for the current date.  But I need the data to go a day backwards so for eg if today is the 29/06/2016 it shouldn't show any data for today but it should load for the 28/06/2016 which is -1 day back.

If I click on 27/06/2016 then it must minus 2 days back from the current day of the 29/06/2016.

So how do I use the current date to minus off the date that was inputed by the user so that PL/SQL knows how many days previously to go back?

```
function Start()
{

 if (document.frmMain["DATEFROM"].value == '{DATEFROM}')
 {
    
    var MONTH_NAMES=new Array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
    var SD = new Date();
    var ED = new Date();
    var dateInMs = SD.getTime();
    
    SD.setTime(dateInMs);

    var month = MONTH_NAMES[SD.getMonth()];
    var day = SD.getDate(); 
    var year = SD.getFullYear();
    var hours = SD.getHours();
    var minutes = SD.getMinutes();
    document.frmMain["DATEFROM"].value = LZ(day) + "-" + month + "-" + year + " 23:59:59";
}
else {
}   }
```

HTML

```
   <tr>
     
        <input name="dtpDATEFROM" type="button" id="dtpDATEFROM" onclick="MM_callJS('popUpCalendar(frmMain.dtpDATEFROM, frmMain.DATEFROM, \'dd-mmm-yyyy 00:00:00\')')" value="...."> </font></td>
      
      </tr>
```

What was tried:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE TRUNC(Date_Production )=trunc(sysdate) to_date('2016/06/29','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to subtract days from a given date you can just do "date - n":

```
select trunc(sysdate) today, trunc(sysdate)-1 yesterday, trunc(sysdate)-2 two_days_ago from dual;
```